# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I am trying to make an HTTP POST request with the flutter plugin HTTP but I am getting an error of the title.
Does anyone know the cause of this since in my other applications this works just perfectly fine?

```
await http.post(Uri.encodeFull("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"), body: {
      "client_id": clientID,
      "redirect_uri": redirectUri,
      "client_secret": appSecret,
      "code": authorizationCode,
      "grant_type": "authorization_code"
    });
```

Answer (score 286, accepted):

To improve compile-time type safety, [`package:http` 0.13.0 introduced breaking changes](https://pub.dev/packages/http/changelog) that made all functions that previously accepted `Uri`s or `String`s now accept *only* `Uri`s instead.  You will need to explicitly use [`Uri.parse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/parse.html) to create `Uri`s from `String`s. (`package:http` formerly called that internally for you.)

| Old Code | Replace With |
| --- | --- |
| `http.get(someString)` | `http.get(Uri.parse(someString))` |
| `http.post(someString)` | `http.post(Uri.parse(someString))` |

(and so on.)

In your specific example, you will need to use:

```dart
await http.post(
  Uri.parse("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"),
  body: {
    "client_id": clientID,
    "redirect_uri": redirectUri,
    "client_secret": appSecret,
    "code": authorizationCode,
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
  });
```

### Edit:

Since I'm still getting upvotes on this answer over a year later, it seems that there are still many people encountering this problem, probably from outdated tutorials.  If so, while I appreciate the upvotes, I strongly recommend leaving comments on those tutorials to request that they be updated.

Comment: What's the difference between `Uri.parse()` and `Uri.https()` or `Uri.http()`?

Comment: @Tayan Read the documentation. `Uri.parse` takes a single URL string.  `Uri.https`/`Uri.http` *build* a `Uri` from parts (a hostname, a path, and a `Map` for query arguments).  If you already have the URL as a `String`, just use `Uri.parse`; it's far less error-prone than using `Uri.https`/`Uri.http` directly.