# Why can't I put a string in the http.post method after update http package in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, http, flutter-dependencies

after I update http package to version 0.13.0 I can't use the http.post() method with my ip address

Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

but on previously version I could use the string as my uri and nothing is wrong or should I convert it to Uri type instead of string with some method?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt7UU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA0R0.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473263/the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-uri)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter should be a `Uri` not a `String`.

To parse your string into an URI you can do this: `Uri.parse(my_string)`