# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri' .dart asynchronous

Tags: flutter, http, dart, asynchronous, future

i use simple asynchronous program with one function but i got this error:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
 print(getData());
}

Future<http.Response> getData() {
 return http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
}
```

can any one help me solve this error ?

Comment: Pass a [uri](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Uri-class.html) to your get method instead of a string.

Comment: I've just executed your code and i did'nt face any error. Which version of dart and http are you using ?

Comment: @SteveNosse yes this problem was not found in previews version , now i use version 2.12.2

Comment: @RobertHarvey how ? can you show in example please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473263/the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-uri)

Answer (score 2):

From `0.13.0-nullsafety.0` version "All APIs which previously allowed a `String` or `Uri` to be passed now require a `Uri`". ([here](https://pub.dev/packages/http/changelog))

You can follow the `README` as an example:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = Uri.parse('https://example.com/whatsit/create');
var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');

print(await http.read('https://example.com/foobar.txt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.13.0-nullsafety.0 of http, you should only use an Uri insteand of a string.

[Changelog] (https://pub.dev/packages/http/changelog)

> **Breaking** All APIs which previously allowed a String or Uri to be passed now require a Uri.

So your could should look like this instead:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  print(getData());
}

Future<http.Response> getData() {
  return http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"));
}
```

Comment: yes this worked for me but how can i print for example users name?