# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri' 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'. final response = await http.post(url,

Tags: flutter, dart

when I run my flutter app I will get this kind of error.

The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  final response = await http.post(url,

here is my .dart file , code where the Error occured.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:save_geez/LoginAndSignupScreen/signup_page.dart';

class Authentication with ChangeNotifier {
  Future<void> Signup(String email, String password) async {
    const url =
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=AIzaSyAnhSx2zHOr0FO9qV-GBXizFg9sy4jz7dw';
    final response = await http.post(url,
        body: json.encode({
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
          "returnSecureToken": true,
        }));
    final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(responseData);
  }
}

                                 ^
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473263/the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-uri)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this, it willsolve your problem:

```
Uri url =Uri.parse('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=AIzaSyAnhSx2zHOr0FO9qV-GBXizFg9sy4jz7dw');
```

The `post` method now uses a `Uri` object, and not a string. Same thing for `get, put, delete`..etc

Parse it as a `Uri` and pass the Uri object, as in the code snippet above. And keep everything else the same as it is, and things should work fine.

Comment: I still get an error when i change my code as you said. when i change the code as you said it is underlined with red color, and when I hove over it I see the message,  Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.

Comment: Use `Uri url = Uri.parse('.....link')` without const, will work.

Comment: Thank you brother it works. without const, but I face this problem when I pass the first challenge, here is the problem I face right now.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66839943/i-flutter-3932-error-code-400-message-missing-custom-token-errors

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the Uri instead of String. you can convert `String` to `Uri`

```
Uri url = Uri.parse("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=AIzaSyAnhSx2zHOr0FO9qV-GBXizFg9sy4jz7dw");
```

Comment: I still get an error when i change my code as you said. when i change the code as you said it is underlined with red color, and when I hove over it I see the message, Const variables must be initialized with a constant value