# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri' in uri.encodeFull()

Tags: flutter, http, dart, url, uri

```
import 'package:weathertempo/model/forecastModel.dart';
import 'package:weathertempo/util/forecast_util.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class Network {
  Future<WeatherForecastModel> getWeatherForecast({String cityName}) async {
       String url =
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=" +
            cityName +
            '&APPID=' +
            Util.appId +
            '&units=metric';

    // Uri.parse(finalUrl);

    final response = await get(Uri.encodeFull(url));
  }
}
```

The error is in 3rd last line when I tried uri.encodeFull(url) it is giving me the error stated above but when I converted the type of url to Uri it keeps giving me the same error. I also even tried uri.parse() function as shown in a comment I don't know what is the problem here if someone know feel free to answer.

Comment: `Uri.encodeFull` takes a `String` as an argument and returns a `String`. `http.get` now expects a `Uri` argument (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66473263/).  You need to call `get(Uri.parse(url))`.

Comment: @jamesdlin ok let me try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin) sir mentioned, you need something like this:

```
Future<String> getWeatherForecast({String cityName}) async {
  final url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/...';
  final response = await get(Uri.parse(Uri.encodeFull(url)));
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `url` in the class definition.  You can `initialize` it in the `initState()`.

```
String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=" +
    cityName +
    '&APPID=' +
    Util.appId +
    '&units=metric';

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  var uri = Uri.encodeFull(url);
}
```

Use something like this way