# Flutter - The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'

Tags: flutter, dart

So, i am trying to create a login/registraion form in dart:

```
    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/apicall.php';

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'email': email, 'password': password};

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
```

But i get this error:

```
Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
 - 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
```

Any way to solve this?

Comment: Correct way: ``var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: json.encode(data));``

Comment: Q: Any way to solve this?  A: Yes.  For example, `var url = Uri.parse(''https://www.mywebsite.com/apicall.php')`;  http.post() expects a [Uri](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri-class.html) object.  "string" is a *DIFFERENT* kind of object.  Uri.parse() is one way to initialize a "Uri" from a "string".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473263/the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-uri) BTW, it is very easy to search for existing questions about specific error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http.post expects an Uri instead of a String. Try this:

```
var uri = Uri.parse('https://www.mywebsite.com/apicall.php');
var response = await http.post(uri , body: json.encode(data));
```

Answer (score 3):

The error here is pretty explicit, the parameter `url` you're using shouldn't be a String but should be an object Uri.
You should refer to the [sample of the http library](https://pub.dev/packages/http/example) to understand how to use this library easily :)