# URL interpolation using Uri class

Tags: flutter, dart, interpolation

I'm having an issue with the Uri class, the code below used to work before the updates but now, the issue is that it uses a **String** instead of a **Uri** URL, I've been trying to update this interpolation to the newest standard with no success. This URL is simply getting data from Firebase with tokens from users that are signed in.

```
final response = await http.get("$_url.json?auth=$_token");
```

I already managed parse the main part of the url:

```
Uri _url = Uri.parse("https://my-project.firebaseio.com/example");
```

The final result used to be something like this:

```
https://my-project.firebaseio.com/example.json?auth=xLwOQ2GEQxPp0h0QD1foHgSyXR52
```

How do I interpolate this URL properly since I have one value that isn't static? (_token)

Comment: `http.get` needs to be used with a `Uri`.  You can interpolate the string the same you did before; you just need to use `Uri.parse` on the resulting string before passing it to `http.get`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473263/the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-uri)

Comment: Thank you @Frank, I needed to parse it again inside `http.get`:

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you for the extra info, It's a little bit more than I need for now but I'll definitely check it for more complex requests

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Uri.https` constructor to create the Uri you then use with `get`.
For example

`var uri = Uri.https('my-project.firebaseio.com', '/example', queryParameters: {'auth': _token})`

See [Uri.http](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html) documentation